# How to get CSS style in snapshot with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-dom, babel-jest

I have the following question, I don't know if its possible to get the result using Jest + snapshot feature.

I have a React components and I'm using Jest to test it.

I want the snapshot to include **css** style not **className**.

Currently my snapshot is like:

```
<div id="main" className="myClass"></div>
```

I would like to have it like:

```
<div id="main" style={Object {"float": "right"}}></div>
```

My App its using **webpack**(*sass-loader*) for parsing **scss**, so over there there are no issues.

It is possible to get this kind of result?

Thanks

Comment: try using Enzyme mount

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible with Jest/Enzyme since style rules can be anywhere: set up explicitly or goes through inheritance from parent element.

Alternatives are using styled-components so you could make snapshots of `styled` block alongside HTML with [jest-styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components).

Or you can use some [visual regression tool](https://www.creativebloq.com/features/the-5-best-visual-regression-testing-tools) that will make and compare screenshots instead of text snapshots.

PS I'm wondering if this is valid thing for automatic testing if a lot of different tests are treated as failed just because we have tuned up theming. Is it worth efforts to analyze and update tests/snapshots/screenshots?

Comment: With screenshots, it's more comprehensive, but slower. If you have all inline styles and snapshot those, it should be faster to run the tests, but they will need to be updated more often. Actually, both would be quite useful. Check the jest snapshot w/inline styles, and if there are changes, check screenshots, and if they are visually the same, you can, a script could automatically update the snapshots. I doubt backstop.js supports this, but it'd probably fall in it's wheelhouse.