# How can I test css properties for a React component using react-testing-library?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-testing-library

The philosophy behind the react-testing-library makes sense to me, but I am struggling to apply it to css properties.

For example, let's say I have a simple toggle component that shows a different background color when clicked:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Toggle.css";

const Toggle = () => {
  const [ selected, setSelected ] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className={selected ? "on" : "off"} onClick={() => setSelected(!selected)}>
      {selected ? "On" : "Off"}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Toggle;
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: green;
}

.off {
  background-color: red;
}
```

How should I test this component? I wrote the following test, which works for inline component styles, but fails when using css classes as shown above.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Toggle from "./Toggle";

const backgroundColor = (element) => window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor;

describe("Toggle", () => {
  it("updates the background color when clicked",  () => {
    render(<Toggle />);
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("Off"));
    expect(backgroundColor(screen.getByText("On"))).toBe("green");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

So that's not what unit or integration test frameworks do. They only test logic.

If you want to test styling then you need an end-to-end/snapshot testing framework like Selenium.

Comment: [This react-testing-library example test](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro) asserts that a button is disabled. I don't see much of a difference between that assertion and the one I'm doing - do you? I would not test most styling in my unit/integration tests, but the example in my question feels different to me. Do you have any recommended reading on this topic?

Comment: There's a huge different, actually. Checking for disabled is checking for an attribute being added -- this is logic. What you're trying to do is check non-inline style. If you would not test your styling in your unit/integration tests, why are you trying to see if an element is green? That's a styling test. While you can test inline style, that is because it is styles attached to the element via attribute. CSS requires a browser-like environment of matching a style sheet to the HTML. This is just basic HTML/CSS stuff. Unless you load the CSS (which a unit test won't) the style can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

For making sure the styling is okay, I prefer snapshot testing. How about firing the event and taking snapshots for both states/cases. Here is what it would look like:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'

 it('should take a snapshot when button is toggled', () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(<App />)
    // Fire the event 
    expect(asFragment(<App />)).toMatchSnapshot()
   })
});
```

Comment: That gives me the css class name, but it does not allow me to check the underlying css properties. Here is the snapshot I got: `<DocumentFragment><div class="on">On</div></DocumentFragment>`

Comment: Personally I would be okay with just testing if that class is set to on since what I am really testing is if there is a theme change on toggle. Tomorrow if the on class  styling changes and I want a red instead of a green, it shouldn't break the test for the toggle logic. But as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550435/how-to-get-css-style-in-snapshot-with-jest and by Devildude, you might have to use inlline styles or a css in js library to get the styles showing up in the snapshot