# React Testing Library Display None CSS Class

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

So I have an element that has a class that has display: none; but when I do expect(screen.getByTestId('header')).not.toBeVisible(); it tells me it's visible. I want to test that the user cannot see anything in this element.

```html
<div className={classNames}>
  <header className={styles.header} data-testid="header">
    <div>
      <span className={styles.eventTime}>{timeText}</span>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.topright}></div>
  </header>
</div>
```

So based on some criteria that classNames variable can add a class that is will set the header class to have display none.

Comment: I assume it works with inline style instead of css classes? Sounds similar to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140331). Basically seems like you cannot test against css properties set by css classes using RTL.

Comment: @srk gotcha. I am use to emberjs that uses qunit that could test this.